# Архивация с удаленного сервера

Tags: php

Есть список картинок, пример:

- `http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/8916787/Elffor.jpg`
- `http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/18417003/Die+Verbannten+Kinder+Evas+die_verbannten_kinder_evas.jpg`
- `http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/43976381/Falkenbach.png`
- `http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/72464110/Avathar+33707_photo.jpg`

Как можно сделать, чтобы пользователю для сохранения предлагался архив с этими картинками?

Comment: слить их в одну папку за архивировать и отослать хидер.

Comment: А если делать не картинки, а например что-то потяжелее? каждый раз сливать и сохранять на сервере?

Comment: не обязательно сохраанять, но тогда нужно постоянно генерить этот архива, а это накладно серваку, так что лучше один раз за архивировать и отдавать до момента обновления картинок :)

Comment: а как именно генерят архивы?)

Comment: можно поискать на тему php и создание архивов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала копируем файл в папку архивирования

```
$from = 'http://somewhere.from';
$to = 'to';

if (!copy($from, $to)) {
    echo "failed to copy $from\n";
}
```

Затем архивируем

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('something.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('to', 'to.zip');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed to archive $to';
}
```